# resolving $routeChangeError for a firebase.com/Parse.com app

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-authentication

What I am doing is a simple Login and Authentication system using ngRoute from AngularJS, Parse.com and $routeChangeError.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error) {
 // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
 // and redirect the user back to the home page
 if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      $location.path('/');
  }
});
```

I am following the same architecture as the app's "Wait and Eat" Firebase example (https://github.com/gordonmzhu/angular-course-demo-app-v2/blob/master/src/app/app.module.js).

In firebase there is a promise to validate if a user is authenticated or not and it returns the error string "AUTH_REQUIRED" when the promise is rejected, then the $routeChangeError is kick off and my page is out of reach (neat!!), but!!!... I want to do the same with Parse.com JS SDK. Currently I have the login and registration working using Parse.User.current() so I want to keep using Parse.com

My direct question is: Is something similar in Parse.com to the firebase.com $requireAuth() promise?

I tried Parse.User.currentAsync() but is not triggering $routeChangeError :(

here is some documentation about firebase.com $requireAuth(): 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers

This is my Auth Service Factory:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.waitList')
    .config(configFunction);

  configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function configFunction($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/waitlist', {
      templateUrl: 'app/waitList/waitList.html',
      controller: 'WaitListController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {user: resolveUser}
    });
  }

  resolveUser.$inject = ['authService'];

  function resolveUser(authService) {
    // return Parse.com - Parse.User.PROMISE?????? 
    return authService.firebaseAuthObject.$requireAuth();

  }

})();
```

App Module:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [
      // Angular modules.
      'ngRoute',

      // Third party modules.
      'firebase',

      // Custom modules.
      ...
    ])
    .config(configFunction)
    .run(runFunction);

  configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

  function configFunction($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }

  runFunction.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location'];

  function runFunction($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, next, previous, error) {
      // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
      // and redirect the user back to the home page
      if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
        $location.path('/');
      }
    });
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a promise with `$q.when` and a rejection with `$q.reject`

```
  function resolveUser(authService, $q) {
    var parseUser = authService.parseUser();
    if (parseUser.authenticated()) {
        return $q.when("AUTH_OK");
    } else {
        return $q.reject("AUTH_REQUIRED");
    };
  }
```